# Get from Lázaro Cárdenas to Puerto Escondido?

Tags: buses, mexico, routes, north-america

Does anybody knows most comfy (=direct) and fastest way between these cities?

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/L%C3%A1zaro-C%C3%A1rdenas/Puerto-Escondido) shows that AltaMar Autobuses goes that route but [on their webpage](https://autobusesaltamar.com.mx/) I don't see Lazaro Cardenas in Origens.

Has anybody had such experience or did that route?

Comment: On r2r I see Costa Line will get you to Acapulco and then Alta Mar the rest of the way. Where do you see Alta Mar for the full trip?

Comment: Oh, yes, my fault. It's a stopover option via Acapulco. So there is no direct route?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but I'm no expert in Mexican bus routes/companies. All of the options I've found for this particular route go through Acapulco.